# C++: error in reading character input using fgets()

Tags: c++, c++14, fgets, gets

I have tried a simple code for using fgets(), as gets() is no more used and don't know anything better to read character input from keyboard.
My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
char a;
fgets(a, 100, stdin);
cout<<a;
return 0;
}
```

I got this error:

```
cpp:13:20: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
 fgets(a, 100, stdin);
                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/cstdio:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:6159,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from jdoodle.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:564:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)'
 extern char *fgets (char *__restrict __s, int __n, FILE *__restrict __stream)
              ^~~~~
```

Then, I have tried

```
#include<iostream>    
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
char *a;
fgets(a, 100, stdin);
cout<<a;
return 0;
}
```

But incurred another error.

It will be appreciated if anyone shows a better method other than using fgets() or solve the above matter.

Comment: .You have just declared a pointer to a character, which you havent initialized (And thus causing an error). Initialize with a size of 100

Comment: what was the error in the first part

Comment: Have you tried `cin >> a;`?

Comment: I have tried but in `cout<<a` it give only the first letter of the input

Comment: `cin >> a` reads your input until the first whitespace. You can use `cin.getline()`. You shouldn't use c (stdio) functions if there are better c++ functions (iostream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)` wrong.
It is intended to read multiple characters from file, actually up to  `n-1` characters, and the last character would be null terminator.

You could use `int getc(FILE *stream)` to read single character like:

```
int a;
if((a = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
  // use a 
  char c = a; // convert to char explicitly
}
```

As you are using c++ an even better way is to use cin stream:

```
char a;
// formatted read(skips whitespace)
cin >> a;

// non-formated read
a = cin.get();
```

and don't forget to check if the operation has been successful after each read:

```
if(cin) {
  // success -> stream is ok
} else {
  // handle read error
}
```

If you want to read multiple characters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char a[100]; // allocate static buffer
  fgets(a, 100, stdin); // read in the buffer
  cout << a;
  return 0;
}
```

Also the c++ way is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s; // string that automatically manages memory
  cin >> s; // reads non-whitespace sequence of characters
  cout << s;
  return 0;
}
```

The other option is to read one line of characters, up to `\n` including whitespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  string s;

  getline(cin, s);
  cout << s;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "But want to use it just like gets(); isn't there a way to use like gets() to read the input of character from the keyboard"? `getline(cin, s);` and `cin.getline()` do what `gets(s)` does.

Comment: You are using c++. You should use `std::string a;`.

Comment: If you look it from another way if you wan't to access 10 characters at the same time you should have a space for those characters. ````a[10]```` is the storage. Another option is to process the data sequentially as it comes - read one character process read another in the place of the first one(you would need some kind of loop).

Answer (score -2):

You need to dereference *a*

```
char a[100];
fgets(&a, 100, stdin);
cout << a << endl;
return 0;
```

Definition of [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) have pointer in first parameter. When you are trying use

```
char a;
```

there is automaticaly allocated space for 1 character.

When you use

```
char *a;
```

you'll have to allocate your space with [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

Comment: `char a;` allocates memory for one `char`. You should allocate memory for 100 `char`s, since you are reading up to 99 characters from stdin. and one `\0` at the end. Use `char a[101];`

Comment: `*** stack smashing detected ***:`  when I used the above one

Comment: The code would cause memory corruption as you ask the fgets to read up to 100 ````char````'s in allocated space for one. So the provided example is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Variable a is an unassigned char pointer. Either declare 'a' as fixed length array:
    char a[100];
or 
allocate memory to 'a' using malloc:

```
a=(char*)malloc( 100*sizeof(char) );
```

Comment: Why `malloc` with c++14? Use `new char[100]`.